# Array cannot be emptied inside a Bash while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create this Bash menu where user can select repos he need. The selection works fine but if the user answer "No" to the question "Do you want to proceed?" the `selected` array is not emptied even if I declare `selected=()`.

E.g.

If I insert `1-2` on the prompt, the selected repos shows the list `repo1` `repo2`. Then, if I now press `n` or `enter` at "Do you want to proceed? [y/N]" question it shows the menu again but if I now enter again `1-2` then the selected repos menu shows `repo1` `repo2` `repo1` `repo2`.

Any hints?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

repos=(repo1 repo2 repo3 repo4 repo5 repo6)


update_cmd() {
    echo "Updating..."
}

select_repos() {
    local cmd=$1
    shift
    local repos_names=("${@}")
    local selected=()
    local item
    local nums
    local num

    if [[ -z "${repos_names[@]}" ]]; then
        echo "No repositories found!"
    else
        while true; do
            echo -e "\n\n"
            PS3=$'\nPlease, select the repositories : (eg: "1 2 3", "1-3", repo name, or "A" for ALL)\n==> '
            select _ in "${repos_names[@]}" ; do
                selected=()
                for item in ${REPLY}; do
                    if [[ "${item}" =~ ^(A)+$ ]]; then
                        selected+=( "${repos_names[@]}" )
                        break
                    fi
                    if [[ "${item}" =~ ^([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)+$ ]]; then
                        nums+=( $( seq ${item//[!0-9]/ } ) )
                    fi
                    if [[ "${item}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                        nums+=( ${item} )
                    fi
                        if [[ "${repos_names[@]}" =~ "${item}" ]]; then
                        selected+=( ${item} )
                    fi
                done
                for num in "${nums[@]}"; do
                    if [ ! -z "${num}" ] && [ 1 -le "${num}" ] && [ "${num}" -le $((${#repos_names[@]})) ]; then
                        selected+=(${repos_names[num - 1]})
                    fi
                done
                [[ ${selected} ]] && break
            done

        
            echo -e "\n"
            echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "                     SELECTED REPOS                     "
            echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
            printf "%b\n" "${selected[@]}"
            echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
            echo
            echo "Do you want to proceed? [y/N]"
            echo -n "==> "
            read -sn 1

            case "${REPLY}" in
                Y|y)
                    ${cmd} "${selected[@]}"
                    break
                    ;;
                N|n|"")
                    continue
                    ;;
                *) 
                    continue
                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
}

select_repos "update_cmd" "${repos[@]}"
```

Comment: Please, read [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You forgot to reset `nums` between iterations.

Comment: @tjm3772 that's the error! Thanks! Please, make the official answer. I will happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't know about this being closed for not being able to be reproduced. I was able to repro it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in how you're calling `select`, and the ordering of these three lines:

```bash
select _ in "${repos_names[@]}" ; do
    selected=()
    for item in ${REPLY}; do
```

Replace those three lines with this and it should work:

```bash
local selected_repo
selected=()
select selected_repo in "${repos_names[@]}" ; do
    for item in ${selected_repo}; do
```

### Other Bugs I Noticed

- `[[ ${selected} ]] && break` only tests if the *first* element of `selected` is non-empty.

  Recommend changing this to `[[ ${#selected[@]} -gt 0 ]] || break`
- `if [[ -z "${repos_names[@]}" ]]; then` weird syntax.

  Recommend changing this to `if [[ ${#repos_names[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then`
- Huge indent after error detection, starting with `while true`.

  Recommend changing this structure to
  `if [[...]]; then print Error; return 1; fi; while true; ...; done` simply to decrease the indent, and make the code easier to follow.
- `[[ "${repos_names[@]}" =~ "${item}" ]]` treats the user input as a regular expression, which might not be what you want. For instance, the user enters `rep*o.*` and suddenly that string is in your `selected` array.

  Recommend replacing this with `[[ " ${repos_names[*]} " = *" ${item} "* ]]` to get a full search using globs for the literal string.
- Mixed old-style and new-style conditionals: `[ ! -z "${num}" ] && [ 1 -le "${num}" ] && [ "${num}" -le $((${#repos_names[@]})) ]`

  Recommend replacing with `[[ -n ${num} && ${num} -gt 0 && ${num} -le ${#repos_names[@]} ]]`

### Bash Debugging Techniques

I use a combination of the following additions to my scripts if I'm refactoring a complex function or just trying to fix a bug:

- Echo each line as it's executing:

```bash
set -x # Turn on dumping
... lines to debug ...
set +x # Turn off dumping
```

Invoking your script with `bash -x myscript.sh` also turns this on.

- Use `declare -p <variable name>` to inspect the contents. E.g. `foo='hello world'; declare -p foo` prints `declare -- foo="hello world"` on stdout.

Comment: Thanks for your help but, as user tjm3772 said, the problem was I forgot to clear the `nums` variable.

Comment: OP: don't forget to pass buggy scripts to https://shellcheck.net